# Resetting a shared pointer captured in a lambda function

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, shared-ptr

(I'm very unsure about the phrasing of the question title. I'm hoping it's not misleading because I really don't know how to summarize this. But I'll try to explain my problem as well as I can.)

In a project, there is something like this (written from memory and simplified):

```
Class A {
private:
    boost::weak_ptr<SomeClassB> b;
public:
    static boost::shared_ptr<SomeClassB> StopSomeProcesses () {
        boost::shared_ptr<SomeClassB> temp (new SomeClassB());
        b = temp;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Now in another project, I need to do something similar to the following:

```
boost::shared_ptr<SomeClassB> obj;
void someFunction () {
    obj = A::StopSomeProcesses();

    auto callback = [](){
        //some other stuff here
        obj.reset();
    };
    NamespaceFromYetAnotherProject::DoSomething(callback);
}
```

What this basically does is while `b` holds a valid object from `A::StopSomeProcesses`, as the name implies, some processes will be stopped. In this case, the processes are stopped while `DoSomething` is executed. At the end, `DoSomething` will call `callback` where `obj` is reset and the stopped processes can now finally continue.

I've done this and it works. However, as much as possible, I'd like to avoid using global variables. I tried doing the following:

```
void someFunction () {
    boost::shared_ptr<SomeClassB> obj;
    obj = A::StopSomeProcesses();

    auto callback = [&obj](){
        //some other stuff here
        obj.reset();
    };
    NamespaceFromYetAnotherProject::DoSomething(callback);
}
```

The above code works. But I'm not sure if I was already in "undefined behavior" territory and just got lucky. Doesn't `obj`'s scope end already? Or does the fact that the lambda was passed as an argument help extend its "life"? If this is safe to do, is that safety lost if `callback` is run on another thread?

I also tried doing this:

```
void someFunction () {
    boost::shared_ptr<SomeClassB> obj;
    obj = A::StopSomeProcesses();

    auto callback = [obj](){
        //some other stuff here
        boost::shared_ptr<SomeClassB> tempObj (new SomeClassB(*obj));
        tempObj.reset();
    };
    NamespaceFromYetAnotherProject::DoSomething(callback);
}
```

But this was something I tried randomly. I wrote it while completely focused on just deleting the object held by the shared pointer. It worked, but I'm not even sure if it's just roundabout or even valid.

Are these attempts going anywhere? Or am I completely going the wrong way? Or should I just stick to using a global variable? Would appreciate any help on how to go about this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a shared_ptr and StopSomeProcesses will internally allocate the memory it points to. Pointers are passed by value so the lifetime of obj is irelevant. Every function call makes a new copy of it as does the binding in the lambda. What matters is what the pointer points too and that was allocated with new and lives on.